# I want to fade the whole background on focus

Tags: background, popup, modal-dialog, fade, blur

I want to fade the whole background on focus the search field. I need only css, If there is a way please let me know I am stuck here for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **so** many ways this can be done:

> 1) Use jQuery to add this class when the search field has focus:

```
.fader {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

> 2) Use jQuery to apply this method when the search field has focus:

```
$("body").fadeOut(2500); // the higher the number the longer it takes to fade
```

> Note for IE 8 compatibility: Use `opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50);`

Comment: Using SASS, LESS, ect. you could accomplish what you're looking to do, but I don't know if that's possible with pure CSS. You're ultimately attempting to reference one CSS rule within another, which is not supported in CSS. Again, jQuery, SASS, LESS will be your best bet.